# AttributeError: 'AbsoluteAnchor' object has no attribute '_from' openpyxl problem

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel reader which also reads images from the excel cells. It should first load the sheet like this:

```py
try:
    wb = load_workbook(FILE_PATH)
    sheet = wb['kala_img']
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print(fp)
    return

# Put your sheet in the loader
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)
```

and also for saving the image I use this:

```
image = image_loader.get(f'C{index + image_counter + 1}')
image.save(file_path)
```

It works fine, but with some excels I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-130:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/app/web/Ordering/product_importer.py", line 50, in import_products_from_excel_file
    image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl_image_loader/sheet_image_loader.py", line 19, in __init__
    row = image.anchor._from.row + 1
AttributeError: 'AbsoluteAnchor' object has no attribute '_from'
```

I have no idea what the difference is, what could be the problem?

Comment: What is openpyxl_image_loader?  Looks like a bug with that.

Comment: what is the problem?